# ASP.NET MVC - Store User in RavenDB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ravendb, membership-provider

What would be the best way to extend the ASP.NET MVC 4 Internet Application such that the `Register` `ActionMethod` in the `AccountController` saves a User object to my RavenDB instance? I would also like to Encrypt the password when storing it to the Database.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few example Membership Providers for RavenDB.

https://github.com/martijnboland/RavenDBMembership by Martijn Boland

https://github.com/wilby/RavenDBMembership - this is a fork of Martins project

https://github.com/bastervrugt/Raven.AspNetProviders

There are also quite a few SO threads on this subject. eg [Membership systems for MVC4 that support RavenDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13666235/membership-systems-for-mvc4-that-support-ravendb)

Comment: I downloaded the project from the first link you gave. Could you further advice how to work with it?